# Programmatic access to wavefunction in Q# for tests

Tags: programming, q#

I'm trying to write unit tests for some small Q# operations. It would be ideal if I could access the wavefunction. Is there a way to get it?

I found [`Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics.DumpRegister`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.diagnostics.dumpregister), but it writes its output to the console or a file in a format intended for humans. I don't want to parse a non-trivial file format as part of writing a unit test.

Comment: Its access is made opaque. The DumpRegister seems unavoidable.

Answer (score 2):

For unit testing, you can use `Assert*` operations which allow you to verify that certain properties of the wavefunction match your expectations, for example, [AssertProbInt operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.arithmetic.assertprobint) or [Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.diagnostics). The documentation mentions some of them [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/libraries/standard/diagnostics); you can also do "Filter by title" for library reference using "Assert" query and check which ones fit your specific goal best.

Comment: Those are much closer to what I need than I was able to find, but they all still need me to specify some additional operation (e.g. to use `AssertAllZero` I need to map the expected state to the 0 state).

Comment: Not necessarily; `AssertProbInt` checks that the amplitude of a certain basis state has the expected absolute value - if you have a state you don't need anything additional. If you can provide a more specific example of what you need I might be able to point you to the best `Assert` operation for that, I use a lot of them for my katas.

Comment: Well, for example, I want to assert that when you apply the QFT to a computational basis state then the output has amplitudes of equal magnitude with a consistent phase increase from amplitude to amplitude. Or, alternatively, I want to assert that my Grover oracle has negated the phase of the correct state. Or I want to verify that a diagonal operator had the right effect.

Comment: Oooooh, if I enable scripts on the docs site it has an actual search. That's somewhat more useful.

Comment: Another example of a complicated assertion is that I'd like to assert that the total weight of states with remainder other than 5 mod 13 is less than some tolerance. Currently I'd have to add new qubits and do simulated operations (very expensive!) in order to make an assertion like this.